# Добавить уникальные лого к меткам

Tags: предложение, метки

На https://stackoverflow.com/ есть уникальные метки с логотипами. Фактически, это логотипы самих языков/фреймворков/субд/etc.

Я предлагаю добавить такую возможность в редактировании меток. Например, как-то стандартизировать тип и размер. Как минимум, это улучшить привлекательность интерфейса, как максимум - его юзибилити.

[image: метки с лого]

Comment: Идея хорошая. Но лично меня они только отвлекают. Ничего разглядеть не могу :)

Comment: @nomnoms12 а мне наоборот нравится, по сути, не приходится вчитываться в метки

Comment: Чтобы не приходилось вчитываться в метки, нужно быть полностью уверенным в том, что значок обозначает. То есть, их нужно утверждать надолго и, желательно, без возможности редактирования в дальнейшем. До тех пор, пока будет неопределённость или возможность их изменить, я против таких нововведений. Но если хорошо это организовать, то идея неплохая.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Тогда добавить возможность делать это только администраторам. Хотя, все правки все равно они просматривают.

Comment: Если взвалить всё на плечи модераторов, то они [будут работать над этим](http://lurkmore.to/Мы_работаем_над_этим) довольно долго. Во-первых, модераторы не являются экспертами по многим меткам, а во-вторых меток очень много. Можно было бы разрешить добавлять значки участникам с высокой репутацией, после чего отправить на голосование экспертам по метке (допустим, имеющим хотя бы бронзовый знак). Но это слишком сложно организовать, не думаю, что кто-то захочет этим заниматься.

Comment: @nomnoms12 На англоязычном SO эти логотипы добавляются именно администрацией, а не модераторами, потому что они являются частью монетизации сайта (компании платят за установку логотипа, чтобы сделать свои метки более узнаваемыми). О том, чтобы назначать всем меткам, речи не идет, только самым популярным.

Comment: И хорошо бы иметь в настройках чекбокс для отключения показа этих логотипов. Но это я размечтался. Скорее введут анимированные лого, голосовые и пр.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, ну Stylebot же есть.